# Having trouble with Jekyll and jQuery Templating due to Liquid engine

Tags: liquid, jekyll

I'm developing a prototype using Jekyll and discovered that Liquid is trying to interpret my jQuery templating code (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

Basically code that should ulitmately be this:

```
{{if PackageDescription}}
<span class="package-and-price">${PackageDescription} - ${PriceString}</span>
{{else}}
<span class="package-and-price">${PriceString}</span>
{{/if}}
<span class="qty-and-edit-item">Qty: ${Count} <a href="/cart">Edit Cart</a></span>
```

Instead becomes this:

```
<span class="package-and-price">${PackageDescription} - ${PriceString}</span>
<span class="package-and-price">${PriceString}</span>
<span class="qty-and-edit-item">Qty: ${Count} <a href="/cart">Edit Cart</a></span>
```

Is there a way/strategy to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enclose that part in [`raw`](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid#No_Liquid_Zone%3a_the_raw_tag) Liquid tags.